# Job graph too large to submit to Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: java, python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to run a job on Dataflow, and whenever I try to submit it to run with DataflowRunner, I receive the following errors from the service:

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request payload size exceeds the limit: x bytes.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request payload size exceeds the limit: x bytes.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "(3754670dbaa1cc6b): The job graph is too large. Please try again with a smaller job graph, or split your job into two or more smaller jobs.",
    "reason" : "badRequest",
    "debugInfo" : "detail: \"(3754670dbaa1cc6b): CreateJob fails due to Spanner error: New value exceeds the maximum size limit for this column in this database: Jobs.CloudWorkflowJob, size: 17278017, limit: 10485760.\"\n"
  } ],
  "message" : "(3754670dbaa1cc6b): The job graph is too large. Please try again with a smaller job graph, or split your job into two or more smaller jobs.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

How can I change my job to be smaller, or increase the job size limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround for this issue that will allow you to increase the size of your job graph to up to 100MB. You can specify this experiment: `--experiments=upload_graph`.

The experiment activates a new submission path which uploads the job file to GCS, and creates the job via an HTTP request that does not contain the job graph - but simply a reference to it.

This has the shortcoming that the UI may not be able to show the job proprely, as it relies on API requests to share the job.

---

An extra note: It is still good practice to reduce the size of your job graph.

An important tip is that sometimes it's possible to create some anonymous DoFns / lambda functions that will have a very large context in their closure, so I recommend looking into any closures in your code, and making sure they're not including very large contexts within themselves.

Perhaps avoiding anonymous lambdas/DoFns will help, as the context will be part of the class, rather than the serialized objects.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some of the suggestions above first, but it looks like the `upload_graph` experiment mentioned in the other answer got removed in later versions.

What solved the issue for me when adding a map with 90k+ entries to an existing pipeline was to introduce this map as a MapSideInput. The general approach is documented in this example from the Scio framework I used to interact with Beam:

https://spotify.github.io/scio/examples/RefreshingSideInputExample.scala.html

There was no noticeable performance impact from this approach.