# Apache Beam With GCP Dataflow throws INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have been trying to migrate data from one BigQuery project to another BigQuery project. When I try to execute it for 20 tables it works fine. But, whenever try to add more tables then it crashes with :

> Reporting job status failed with error code: INVALID_ARGUMENT

My Code looks like:

```
PCollection<TableRow> rows;
List<String> tablesNames = fetchTablesFromSourceBigQuery();
PipelineOptionsFactory.register(MyOptions.class);
MyOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(MyOptions.class);
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
for(String tableName: tableNames){
   rows = p.apply("Reading from table",  BigQueryIO.readTableRows().from("sourceProject:sourceDataset."+tableName);
   rows.apply("Writing to table", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to("destProject:destDataset."+tableName);
}
p.run();
```

Comment: Do you have more error logs? I'm just curious: do you have transformations? Usually this can easily be done from BigQuery itself. For example: 

> CREATE TABLE `destProject.destDataset.destTable` AS (SELECT * FROM `sourceProject.sourceDataset.sourceTable`)

Comment: This is the only error log that I am getting when executing this dataflow job.

Comment: I don't have transformations. I just want to load the data using apache beam and write the data into another dataset. Reason behind using pipeline of apache beam is to show the dataflow at each step of table copying.

Comment: This issue seems to be because of the [job graph is too large](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#job-graph-too-large). Can you try including the flag `--experiments=upload_graph` in your code. You can refer to this [code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowRunner.java#L881) and [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66430731/job-graph-too-large-to-submit-to-google-cloud-dataflow/66430732#66430732) for more information.

Comment: Hi @WasifKirmani, Did the above comment help you in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused because the [job graph is too large](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#job-graph-too-large).

The Issue can be resolved by including the flag `--experiments=upload_graph` in the code.

For more information this [code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowRunner.java#L881) and [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66430731/job-graph-too-large-to-submit-to-google-cloud-dataflow/66430732#66430732) can be referred.